# unable locate element when using by,linktext

Tags: css, css-selectors, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to test the filter function at

```
https://todomvc.com/examples/vue/
```

user can click 'All' 'Active' or 'Completed' to filter the list.

the java class:

```
public static By filterButtonWithLabel(String filters) {
    return By.linkText(filters);
}
```

error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":""Active""}
```

what is this error about? is that telling i cannot use `by.linktext`?

Answer (score 0):

I just realize it is the steps problem
I should not use double quote, just type the string "Completed" directly.

```
And I filter the list to show Completed tasks
```